# How is a reference variable represented in memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, reference

```
int num = 0;
int *ptrNum = &num;
int &refNum = num;
```

[image]

Which one is the correct representation of reference variable in the memory-table 1 or table 2?
If table 2,then why a pointer is an object and a reference isn't?
If both representations are incorrect then please provide a correct representation and an explanation for why a reference isn't an object.

Comment: The storage of reference variables is unspecified.

Comment: I think this is a good, well-written question. That the OP doesn't know any better is beside the point.

Comment: The problem with the above code is that "Table 3: /nothing/ "  is also a valid _and realistic_ result! The use of `refNum` often affects its representation, so the question is incomplete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Which one is the correct representation of reference variable in the memory-table 1 or table 2?

It could be either, or neither.

In this case, there is no need for storing the address of the object, so the table 1 would be enough. In another example, an address of the referenced variable could be needed. Such as when the reference is an argument of a non-inlined function.

> please provide a correct representation

draft N4140 of the C++ standard [dcl.ref]/4:

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage

*How* it could be stored is not specified at all.

> an explanation for why a reference isn't an object.

The same document defines object as

[intro.object]/1

> ... An object is a region of storage ...

If a reference is not defined to have storage, then it's not defined to be an object.

Comment: I don't think the "pass the reference to the non-inlined function" case mandated the use of representation 2 either. The compiler has to know `x1` or at least how to calculate it, in order to store it in `x2`. But if it knows this, it can also use this knowledge when pushing `x1` directly on the call stack.

Comment: @MSalters I don't think so either. As I said, in that case (I modfied the wording for clarity) the address of the referenced variable would be needed (stored *on the call stack*, as you say). If the address is already stored somewhere like in OP's example, then would assume a compiler is allowed to reuse it.